# How do you deep clone a persistent entity in ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, deep-copy

I have a persistent entity that I'm using as a template:

```
Company
    Locations
        Departments
            Employees
```

In other words, a `Company` contains many `Locations`, which contains many `Departments`, which contains many `Employees`. I have one `Company` set up as a template that should be copied when a new company is created. However, this template is persistent in the database. I tried using the following code to deep clone it:

```
var template = EntityLoadByPK("Company", 13);
var company =  Duplicate(template);
EntitySave(company);
```

But I receive an error says that the entity is not attached to the session. So then I tried to assign 0 to all the IDs before saving:

```
company.setId(0);
for (location in company.getLocations())
{
    location.setId(0);
    // more nested for loops
}
```

But I receive a similar error. Finally, I tried to do a direct 1:1 copy of the properties:

```
var newCompany = EntityNew("Company");
newCompany.setName(company.getName());
newCompany.setCEO(company.getCEO());
// etc...
```

But this gets more and more cumbersome the deeper the object graph goes. Is there an easier way of deep cloning a persistent entity so that you get a brand new transient entity, including all of its child collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last time I encountered the same situation, I just wrote a clone-like method in the root CFC.  Cannot call it `clone` btw, 'cause it's reserved I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`EntityMerge`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSfd7453be0f56bba437188258123092b394c-7fff.html)? You should be able to duplicate an ORM object, NULL out the IDs, and then Merge it back into the session.

Comment: I gave this a try and it works pretty well. One thing to keep in mind is that it duplicates EVERYTHING, so if you have bidirectional relationships that go back up the tree, you will end up duplicating your entire database. In the end, I went with Henry's solution because I wanted more finely-grained control over the duplication process, although it's vastly more code doing it that way.