# Multiple Hibernate Sessions in ColdFusion?

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm working on a project that requires we are able to modify data on an ORM entity, but not have it persisted back to the database. Essentially, we need to modify the object and pass it in to a service that performs some calculations on the data, and then end the request with none of that data actually being persisted. The catch is that the service that performs the calculations **does** need to persist some data (run logs, calculation results). This means we can't just clear the whole session once the process has completed.

The entity we're working with is relatively complex (at least a dozen relationships and many more simple properties), so it's not optimal to evict the entity and all of its related entities from the session prior to flushing. To make things more difficult, there are some `ormFlush()` calls within the service that performs the calculations, which makes manually evicting the entity next to impossible. Due to the large number of relationships, it's not feasible to eager load everything up front and then evict it all before we send it off to the service.

Because of these concerns, I am attempting to open a second Hibernate session (basically, a sandbox) that will never be flushed. We can load the entity and make any changes we need within that session without worrying about the changes persisting to the database.

So far it has been successful with one exception: I'm unable to call the implicit "has" methods (e.g. `hasFoo()`, `hasBar()`) on the entity - it results in a NullPointerException.

Example code:

```
ormSession = ormGetSessionFactory().openSession();
person = ormSession.load( "person", javaCast( "int", 123 ) );

// assume person has a o2m relationship for "brother"
writeOutput( person.hasBrother() );
```

This results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
coldfusion.orm.ImplicitRelationUDF.runHasMethodWithNoArgs(ImplicitRelationUDF.java:410) at 
coldfusion.orm.ImplicitRelationUDF.invoke(ImplicitRelationUDF.java:246) at 
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:431) at 
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:414) at 
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2432) at 
cfsean2ecfm1294924799.runPage(C:\websites\test.cfm:11)
```

My hunch is that ImplicitRelationUDF.java is attempting to use the "standard" CF Hibernate session and is failing because this entity is loaded in a different session, but I don't know how to research further at this point.

I took another approach that still doesn't work, but it's (maybe) food for thought. It throws the same error as the code above.

```
transaction {
    person = entityLoadByPK( "person", 123 );
    transaction action="rollback";
}

writeOutput( person.hasBrother() );
```

I'm open to solutions to the specific problem (fixing has*) or the more general problem of modifying an entity and ensuring that the data doesn't get persisted back to the DB.

Comment: You could try setting `flushatrequestend=false` in Application.cfc. This means that the only way to commit ORM changes is to manually call `ORMFlush()` AFTER you have called `entitySave()`. In the service that needs to persist data, you can simply call `ORMFlush()` after you are done calling `entitySave()` on those objects.

Comment: @ScottStroz When ORM is flushed - manually or automatically via `flushatrequestend` - it will persist any persistent (e.g. loaded rather than created via new/entityNew) entity with dirty properties regardless of `entitySave()` calls.

Comment: Crap....forgot about that. Stupid Hibernate.

Comment: What if you completely decouple that logic into something that can be run in a separate thread?

Comment: @BradWood I'm not sure I'm following - can you elaborate please?

Comment: I have no idea if it'll work on a CFC, but evict() can help with things like this in raw Javaland:

    session = ormSetSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.evict( theThingYouWantOut )

One caveat is that you'll need to load any associated associations _before_ you evict: it's no longer going to have a session through which to do these things.

Comment: @JoeRinehart Yah, eager loading everything that hangs off this entity is not something I want to do. Definitely a last resort type of option.

Answer (score 2):

Set the session default to be readonly

```
ormSession = ormGetSessionFactory().openSession();
ormSession.setDefaultReadOnly( true );
person = ormSession.load( "person", javaCast( "int", 123 ) );
```

Anything you call in the session will be readonly

Comment: Sam, the entity will be read only, but we still won't have access to the implicit has* methods.

Answer (score 0):

I know the entity you're working with is relatively complex, but all I can think of right now is to write a clone method in it and clone everything it has into a new instance that doesn't attach to any session, and use that pass that cloned instance to your service that requires orm persistent.

There may be better solution but if time is a constraint I'm pretty sure this will work.

[How do you deep clone a persistent entity in ColdFusion ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592706/how-do-you-deep-clone-a-persistent-entity-in-coldfusion-orm)

I'd be happy to learn how to deal with this with ORM session, as I've read that it's not implemented well in ColdFusion.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but I'd realllly like to avoid loading everything up front, which we'd need to do if we were to clone the entity.

Comment: Provided you have lazy load in place, instead of writing a clone method and clone everything, you can shallow copy whatever you need into a new instance in the service layer.  It's doable, but it's rather dumb.  Hope some hibernate session expert can give you a better solution.